# If $n$ is square-free and $n+1 \mid \sigma(n)$, is $n$ a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, divisibility, conjectures

As the title says, is $n$ being square-free together with $n+1 \mid \sigma(n)$ sufficient to show $n$ is prime?

It is well-known that if $\varphi(n)\mid n-1$ and $n+1 \mid \sigma(n)$, then $n$ is a prime (see e.g. [An integer is prime iff $\phi(n) \mid n-1$ and $n+1 \mid \sigma (n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528722/an-integer-is-prime-iff-phin-mid-n-1-and-n1-mid-sigma-n)). Also it is a well-known open problem - [Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) - whether $\varphi(n)\mid n-1$ itself implies that $n$ is a prime. Since $\varphi(n)\mid n-1$ implies that $n$ is square-free, this makes me wondering what is known about the problem in between these two, i.e. $n$ being square-free together with $n+1 \mid \sigma(n)$.

I've checked by brute force that the conjecture holds up for $n$ being a product of any of the first $31$ primes. As for the proof, we can rule out product of two primes easily as $n=pq$ and $pq+1\mid \sigma(n)=(p+1)(q+1)=pq+p+q+1$ implies $pq+1\mid p+q$ and then we show $pq+1>p+q$ contradicts this result. But it does not seem to generalize to more primes that simply. It might be also that this problem is open, in that case I have yet to find a reference.

**Update:** I've found a proof that only even $n$ that satisfies the conditions is $n=2$, pushing the possible counterexample to odd numbers only.

To see this let $n=2\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i$ where $p_i=2^{e_i}d_i-1$ with $e_i \geq 1$ and $d_i$ odd. Now we have two possibilities, either $e_i=1$, or $e_i \geq 2$. If $e_i=1$, then $d_i \geq 3$, and we have

$$
2^{e_i}d_i-1 \geq 2d_i-1\geq \sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}} d_i
$$
where the last inequality follows from $(2-\sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}})d_i\geq (2-\sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}})3\geq 1$, which holds for $k \geq 1$.

If on the other hand $e_i\geq 2$, then

$$
2^{e_i}d_i-1 \geq 4d_i-1\geq \sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}} d_i
$$
this time because $(4-\sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}})d_i\geq (4-\sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}})\cdot 1\geq 1$, which again holds for $k \geq 1$.

Either way we get $2^{e_i}d_i-1\geq \sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}} d_i$. But then
$$
n+1=2\prod_{i=1}^{k}(2^{e_i}d_i-1)+1\geq 2 \prod_{i=1}^k \sqrt[k]{\frac{3}{2}} d_i +1=3\prod_{i=1}^{k}d_i+1
$$
and at the same time
$$
n+1\mid\sigma(n)=(2+1)\prod_{i=1}^{k} 2^{e_i}d_i=3\cdot 2^{\sum e_i}\prod_{i=1}^k d_i.
$$
Since $n+1$ is odd, we have $n+1 \mid 3\prod_{i=1}^k d_i$ and so $n+1 \leq 3\prod_{i=1}^k d_i$. But these results are contradictory as we have
$$
3\prod_{i=1}^{k}d_i+1\leq n+1 \leq 3\prod_{i=1}^k d_i.
$$

**Update 2:** Furthermore any counterexample must have $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. This follows from C.S.'s argument in the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4166913/290240):
If $4\mid n-1$, then $2\mid n+1$ and $4\nmid n+1$. So $v_2(n+1)=1$. If $n$ has $k$ odd prime factors then $2^k \mid \sigma(n)$.
But then $2^{k-1}\mid \frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}$ and in turn
$$
2^{k-1}\leq \frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}<\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\prod_{p\mid n} \frac{p+1}{p}\leq \prod (1+\frac{1}{3})=\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)^k
$$
which does not hold for $k \geq 2$, so $k=1$ and $n$ is a prime.

Comment: The criterion is sufficient upto $n=10^8$. With the help of your brute force, we can probably extend the search limit significantly , since a counterexample must have a prime factor at least $131$

Comment: Additionally , we have $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}>\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}\ge 2$ , hence $n$ must be abundant, if a counterexample exists there is probably one with $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\approx 2$. Moreover, $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ must be an almost integer , extremely near to an integer $k\ge 2$

Comment: Nice problem (+1) , maybesome someone can refute $3$ or $4$ prime factors. Probably this can be done. Maybe, this can be further extended.

Comment: There is another property that is necessary for a counterexample making it very unlikely that there is one : For every prime divisor $q$ of $n+1$ , there must be a prime $p\mid n$ such that $q\mid (p+1)$ , that is $q\le p+1$. In particular , if $q$ is the largest prime factor of $n+1$ and $p$ the largest prime factor of $n$ , we must have $q\le p+1$.

Comment: If $3$ and $3'$ were "distinct" primes, then $n=7\cdot3\cdot3'$ would work :-)

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, it convinces me even more the counterexample is very unlikely. I've managed to prove that no even counterexample exists, see updated post.

Comment: this is gotta be solvable by just bounding better. For example, by using a very crude bound $p_k\geq 2k+1$, one get:
$$1 < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n+1} < \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi n}{2}}$$

Comment: That even numbers cannot be a counterexample is a significant breakthrough , if we define $r:=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}$ , this can immediately be seen if $r\equiv 2\mod 4$ , in particular if $r=2$ , since then for even $n$ , $r(n+1)$ would not be divisible by $4$ , but $\sigma(n)$ must be divisible by $4$ since $n$ has at least two odd prime factors. Also the number of necessary prime factors grows with the least prime factor.

Comment: If $n$ must just be composite , not necessarily squarefree , the condition $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}$ is still rarely satisfied and all solutions I found so far are even and only one is not divisible by $4$ : $$20\ 104\ 464\ 650\ 1952\ 130304\ 522752\ 8382464\ 134193152$$

Comment: See also the linked question : $650$ seems to be special. It is the only solution I found so far not fitting in the family given there.

Comment: I was not aware of the "well known" crtierion in the linkes question.

Comment: Yea I always assume something is well-known if I found it :) Anyway It turns out counterexample must be $n \equiv 3  \pmod 4$, updated the post again. So that means we must have odd number of $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ prime factors.

Comment: It also seems that this problem might be a special case of more general phenomenom: Let $S$ be a finite subset of positive integers such that $\prod_{n\in S}n+1 \mid \prod_{n \in S}(n+1)$, is then $|S|=1$? But I guess that is a bit off-topic here (I haven't found a counterexample to that either though).

Comment: @Sil your recent conjecture about subsets of positive integers fails in the case $S=\{1,3,11,31\}$, since then $1+\prod_{n\in S} n = 1024$, which is a factor of $3072 = \prod_{n\in S}(n+1)$. The fact that $1\in S$ is doing some work here, since it gives a free factor of two without affecting our prospective divisor. If not for that $1$, this would also be a counter example to your primary question, but $1$ is not prime, so it doesn't work. I haven't yet found any other counter examples.

Comment: @JadeVanadium Good point, interesting how really everything except $1$ in that example is a prime. I've checked my original code and it had a bug, I've fixed it now and found many others such as $\{8,5,2\}$ or $\{49,22,4,2\}$, so the generalized version indeed does not hold even if we restrict to integers $>1$, but if we consider only odd numbers greater than $1$ then I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a proof that $n$ can't have just three **odd** prime factors, say $n=pqr$ where $p<q<r$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&pqr+1|pqr+pq+pr+qr+p+q+r+1 \\&\implies
& pqr+1|pq+pr+qr+p+q+r 
\end{eqnarray*}

We can make use of the following:
$r-1>q>p+1$ and obtain $qr>(p+1)r$, $qr>(p+1)(q+1)$.

Adding these up gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
pqr\geq3qr&>&qr+(p+1)r+(p+1)(q+1)\\
&=&pq+pr+qr+p+q+r+1
\end{eqnarray*}

---

We can make this observation.

If $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i$, i.e. it has $k$ prime factors and if $p_i\geq \frac{1}{2^{1/k}-1}$ for each $1\leq i\leq k$, then we have $$1<\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}<\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}<2$$

In a similar vein, if $n=pqrs$ has 4 **odd** prime factors, then $$1<\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}=\frac{(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(s+1)}{pqrs+1}
\leq \frac{4\times6\times8\times12}{3\times 5\times 7\times 11 +1}<2$$

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the case of three prime factors as even $n$ can be ruled out altogether. For the four odd prime factors though, I am not sure I follow, did you use $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(s+1) \leq 4\times6\times8\times12$? That might not hold..

Comment: @Sil I think they meant for the entire fraction. That is, increasing any of the primes results in a larger increase in the denominator than in the numerator.

Comment: @EricSnyder Oh yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Interestingly, there are some very-near integers and extremely-near-rationals in the sequence $$q=\frac {\prod^n_{i=1} (p_i+1)}{1 + \prod^n_{i=1} p_i}$$ when including $p_1 = 2$, so for example for $n=2, q=(3 \times 4)/(2 \times 3 +1) = 12/7$ and so on. Near hits: $n=5, q \approx 3 - (1/109); \ n=6, q \approx 29/9; \ n=11, q \approx 4+(1/539); \ n=15, q \approx 22/5; \ n=24, q \approx 5+(1/97)$.

Comment: That $n$ must be odd increases the number of necessary prime factors to $5$. And if $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n+1}>2$ or $3\nmid n$ , then we need even $9$ prime factors.

Comment: Using this technique, it's not too difficult to prove via brute force that $n$ must have a rather large number of prime factors. In particular since $n$ is square free, by comparison to the prime harmonic series we have $\sigma(n)/(n+1)$ bounded by $O(\log(\log(k)))$, where $k$ is the number of prime factors of $n$. Of course, $k$ itself already grows logarithmically with $n$, so we should expect hypothetical counter examples to be incredibly large, if they exist.